# Fiddler: Get Client Certificate from IPhone App to log HTTPS traffic

Tags: ios, https, certificate, fiddler, traffic

I want to debug some HTTPS traffic from an IPhone app using Fiddler.

After installing the Fiddler-generated certificate on the IPhone, I am able to see most of the HTTPS-Traffic but unfortunately the HTTPS-Requests I want to debug use a client certificate which I have to copy to my PC in order to see the traffic.

Is there a general way to download that specific certificate?